# How to find Radio button control within Gridview

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, findcontrol

I am trying to find a radiobutton control within a gridview but I keep getting the output of `0` for whatever radiobutton I select. I want each radiobutton to be assigned the value of 1-4 and then whatever radiobutton selected, it will be outputted to a label.

VB code

```
 Dim SelectNumber As Integer

 For Each row As GridViewRow In MyGridView.Rows

        Dim radbtn1 As RadioButton = TryCast(row.FindControl("a1"), RadioButton)
        Dim radbtn2 As RadioButton = TryCast(row.FindControl("a2"), RadioButton)
        Dim radbtn3 As RadioButton = TryCast(row.FindControl("a3"), RadioButton)
        Dim radbtn4 As RadioButton = TryCast(row.FindControl("a4"), RadioButton)


        If radbtn1.Checked = True Then
            SelectNumber = 1
        ElseIf radbtn2.Checked = True Then
            SelectNumber = 2
        ElseIf radbtn3.Checked = True Then
            SelectNumber = 3
        ElseIf radbtn4.Checked = True Then
            SelectNumber = 4
        End If


    Next

    lblOutput.Text = SelectNumber
```

Source code

```
 <asp:GridView ShowHeader="false" AutoGenerateColumns="false" ID="MyGridView" runat="server" GridLines="None">
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField>

                <ItemTemplate>

                    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="QuestionID" Text='<%# Eval("QuestionID")%>' />
                    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="Question" Text='<%# Eval("Question")%>' /><br />
                    <asp:RadioButton GroupName="gnA" Text='<%# Eval("a1")%>' runat="server" ID="ans1" /><br />
                    <asp:RadioButton GroupName="gnA" Text='<%# Eval("a2")%>' runat="server" ID="ans2" /><br />
                    <asp:RadioButton GroupName="gnA" Text='<%# Eval("a3")%>' runat="server" ID="ans3"  /><br />                  
                    <asp:RadioButton GroupName="gnA" Text='<%# Eval("a4")%>' runat="server" ID="ans4" /><hr />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>

        </Columns>

    </asp:GridView>

<asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Complete" />
   <asp:Label ID="lblOutput" runat="server" Text="" />
```

Comment: Where is the code located that you've shown? I'm pretty sure that the reason for this issue is that you databind the grid on every postback instead of only `If Not Page.IsPostback`. Then no one is checked and the `SelectNumber` keeps it's default value which is `0`

Comment: That resolved the issue - Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure that the reason for this issue is that you databind the grid on every postback instead of only `If Not Page.IsPostback`. Then no one is checked and the `SelectNumber` keeps it's default value which is `0`

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
        ' DataBind the GridView here or call a method therefore '
    End If
End Sub
```